# Show existence for monotone likelihood ratio (MLR) in X

Tags: statistics, exponential-family

I am trying to show that if we have an observation with density
$$f_\theta (x)=\frac{1}{2}\exp(-|x-\theta|), \ \ x\in\mathbb{R}$$ where $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ is an unknown parameter, then the model has monotone likelihood ratio (MLR) in X.

I have tried getting the density on the form of an exponential family to show that the natural parameter is strictly increasing in $\theta$, since the result then follows. But I have not really suceeded. I have only come to the point:
$$f_\theta (x)=\frac{1}{2}\exp(-\sqrt{(x^2+\theta^2-2x\theta)})$$

How do I get this into the right form?

Comment: What makes you think this (Laplace distributions with fixed scale but varying locations) is an exponential family?   Another approach might be to consider the three parts of the likelihood ratio with parameters $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ when $x$ is below both, above both, or between them

Comment: I sounds like a good idea with a different approach, since I can clearly not get the exponential family think to work. Can you clarify how one uses this likelihood ratio method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you consider two different values of $\theta$, say $\theta_1 < \theta_2$, and then consider the ratio $\dfrac{f_{\theta_2} (x)}{f_{\theta_1} (x)}$:

- for $x \le \theta_1$ you get $\frac{\frac{1}{2}\exp(x-\theta_2)}{\frac{1}{2}\exp(x-\theta_1)} = \exp(\theta_1-\theta_2)$, which is a constant between $0$ and $1$
- for $x \ge \theta_2$ you get $\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}\exp(\theta_2-x)}{\frac{1}{2}\exp(\theta_1-x)} = \exp(\theta_2-\theta_1)$, which is a constant above $1$
- for $\theta_1 \le x \le \theta_2$ you get $\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}\exp(x-\theta_2)}{\frac{1}{2}\exp(\theta_1-x)} = \exp(2x-\theta_2-\theta_1)$, which is a strictly increasing function of $x$, with values increasing from the lower constant to the higher constant.

So the ratio overall is a *weakly* increasing function of $x$, but constant over wide intervals, and this may for example prevent you from arguing there is a unique optimal critical region for some hypothesis testing.

Comment: Thank you for so much. This was a very nice answer.